# Scala Play Framework: Header doesn't exists

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to run play application and it runs correctly. However, while serving to few APIs, I get following error:

```
[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Header doesn't exist
[error] application - 

! @714mk098l - Internal server error, for (POST) [/ivi/customer/login/] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: Header doesn't exist]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_2.10-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_2.10-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.10-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.10-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Header doesn't exist
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27) ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
    at play.api.mvc.Headers$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Http.scala:338) ~[play_2.10-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.api.mvc.Headers$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Http.scala:338) ~[play_2.10-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
    at play.api.mvc.Headers$class.apply(Http.scala:338) ~[play_2.10-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
```

I feel like this should related to configuration rather than code issue. Can someone please guide here?

Comment: Looks like a code issue and it is definitely a code issue, if any of the other `Action`s perform fine in your application. We will need to look at the code your `/ivi/customer/login/` `Action` to try to come up with a solution.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, it was code issue.
Actual problem was that API method was trying to read some header from HTTP request and that header was not present.
Few weeks back, When secret token is changed in application.conf file, I faced similar issue that's why I felt like this is configuration issue.

Comment: Sarvesh, Can you give me your mail id or linked in id?

Comment: Sure. https://in.linkedin.com/in/sarveshseri